.htaccess 301 rewrite rules for wildcard automated rewrite rules
Can someone help me with doing a 1 line rewrite rule so that I don't have to do 1 by 1 for article urls
example of old URL:
olddomain.com/article/12/name-of-the-old-page.html

which I just want to wild card to a single new URL like so
olddomain.com/article/*/*.html > newdomain.com/news/

I have been playing around with some rules but not sure im doing correctly
Redirect 301 /article/*/*.html https://www.newdomain.com/news/

also tried this
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^article/\*/\*\.html$ https://www.newdomain.com/news/? [R=301,L]


I worked it out, so for anyone else wanting a solution here it is
RedirectMatch 301 ^/article/.*$ https://www.newdomain.com/news/

Works a treat

RedirectMatch 301 ^/article/ https://www.newdomain.com/news/
